# How to copy data in girdview using session?

Tags: asp.net

I am a newbie in using asp.net I just wanna know on how to copy data in the gridview using session. The scenario is like is the data from the grid should be transfer to other .aspx pages and store to another gridview. Please Help me:) Thanks in advance.

Session("data")=GridView1? Is this possible...

Comment: Why not just "copy" the "table" that the Gridview binds to? How do you bind data to your Gridview?

Comment: I wanna transfer that data from gridview to other aspx. page

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code in c#, you can change in vb.net, according to your need.

Then in order to get the data

If DataSource of GridView1 is a DataTable

```
  DataTable dt = (DataTable)GridView1.DataSource;
  Session["data"] = dt;
```

Use session in the other page

Comment: what if if the GridView is not a datatable the data is  not manually added. it comes from a list of item listed on a gridview and that data that listed are going to transfer to other page